# Quadtree on android maps utils

Tags: android, google-maps, polygon, quadtree

I'm developing a android application with google maps v2 that draw polygons on the google maps. But now i have to identify a click on a certain polygon and popup a window.

[I found this useful library on github](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils)

This library has the method containsLocation implemented. This method receives a LatLng (from click on the map) and a List (the polygon). This is fine but if i have 1 million polygon in the map i cant iterate all and test if a certain LatLng belongs to a certain Polygon. I remember that i can use a quadtree to get more performance and this library also implements a quadtree but it uses point. What is the best way of doing this? May i have to reimplement this quadtree for a quadtree of LatLng ? Or in each click i have to convert this click to a point and search on a point quadtree?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to implement a quadtree that stores the polygons, then query the tree to see which polygon (if any) contains the LatLng. If you search around I'm sure you can find a decent implementation.

Comment: I'm searching but i cant find any quadtree implemented to store polygons with LatLng. The best i can found was this [link](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/quadtree/PointQuadTree.java)quadtree storing items with points[/link] . But i have som e questions. Whats the bounds of this quadtree with LatLng? If i store polygons (with multiple LatLngs point) what LatLng i use to store the polygon?

Comment: LatLng is the same as x,y. Read this paper out storing polygons in quadtrees: http://infolab.usc.edu/csci585/Spring2008/den_ar/p182-samet.pdf . You can use a PM quadtree to find the region in which a point lies (which is what you want to do): https://www.cs.umd.edu/users/meesh/420/Notes/KingaNotes/pm_quadtree_evan.ppt
I'm sure you can find more resources online if you look up PM quadtree.

Answer (score 3):

you cannot use a Point- Quadtree, you need an Object-Quadtree for your Polygons. An object quadree uses the bounding box of the polygon or any object for adding into the tree.

you dont need to consider latLong, use x,y with x= longitude, and y = Latitude.

Consider reading Hanan Sammet: Foundations of multidimensional data structures.

Comment: With a object-quadtree can i store in the quadtree polylines, polygons and points(drawed on map with small circle)? I will have all this shapes over the map and when i click in the map i need to give the LatLng click point to the quadtree and she has to give me a list of Points, Polylines or Polygons that can contain this LatLng. So, after that, i will try every element on this returned list and test if LatLng is contained by a element and so identify the click on certain shape. I'm thinking right? This is best way to do this? Can i found any open source implement library that can do that?